# Remove application name after localhost in jetty

Tags: maven, jetty

I build application using maven and run it using jetty plugin. Lets name of application be AAA, then, how can i configure jetty for entering on my application by URL `http://localhost:PORT/` instead of `http://localhost:PORT/AAA/`
I saw answers when using Tomcat, but i am intresting in jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `<contextPath>` to `/` in the plugin configuration as documented [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) or [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin#Configuring_Your_WebApp) (based on the version of the plugin used.

```
<contextPath>/</contextPath>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what im looking for.