# Web application Path when using maven and Jetty

Tags: java, maven, build, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using maven and jetty for my web application. I give the command `mvn jetty:run` to run the maven/jetty which also will load my web application. But the path I get to use to access is `http://localhost:8080/filename.jsp` while I want it to be `http://localhost:8080/myappname/filename.jsp`

How to get this done ? Please let me know if I've to post specific files from my web app for you to be able to solve this.

I found other way around at [Remove application name after localhost in jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152744/remove-application-name-after-localhost-in-jetty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From these docs:  http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal

I think you just need to configure the contextPath in your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <webApp>
      <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
    </webApp>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```